# How to get max value in List<Map<String, Object>> at Java8

Tags: java, java-8

I'm trying to get max value in Java 8.

It consist of `List<Map<String,Object>>`.

Before Java 8 :

```
int max = 0;
for(Map<String, Object> map : list) {
    int tmp = map.get("A");
    if(tmp>max)
       max=tmp;
}
```

This will show the largest number of key "A".

I tried to do the same in Java 8, but I can't get the max value.

Comment: this doesn´t really compile as `map.get("A")` returns an `Object` and not an `int`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the values are expected to be integer, I'd change the type of the `Map` to `Map<String,Integer>`:

```
List<Map<String,Integer>> list;
```

Then you can find the maximum with:

```
int max = list.stream()
             .map(map->map.get("A"))
             .filter(Objects::nonNull)
             .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
             .max()
             .orElse(someDefaultValue);
```

You can make it shorter by using `getOrDefault` instead of `get` to avoid `null` values:

```
int max = list.stream()
             .mapToInt(map->map.getOrDefault("A",Integer.MIN_VALUE))
             .max();
             .orElse(someDefaultValue);
```

Comment: Is it possible to cast to a lambda expression if the map's value is an object?

Comment: @pamiers The cast will throw an exception if the runtime type of the object doesn't match the type you are trying to cast it to.

Comment: `IntStream.max` returns an `OptionalInt`.

Comment: The `getOrDefault` variant is not recommended, as it can lead to getting `Integer.MIN_VALUE` as final result.

Comment: @Holger Thanks for the comments. As for the second comment, that depends on what is expected to be returned when no values matching the "A" key are present.

Answer (score 1):

```
int max = listMap.stream()                               
       .flatMap(c -> c.entrySet().stream()) 
       .max(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue)).get().getValue();
```